# Unexpected errors in object_detection project, absolutely dumbfounded

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, gpu, object-detection

I am trying to learn `tensorflow` by following this tutorial: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10 After executing step 2g, my code appears online and I have to check it for errors. When I did so, I received many errors, some seemingly unwarranted (for example 'os' is not defined when it clearly was). I viewed both the "common errors" section of the GitHub as well as the comments section but nobody seems to have the same issues as me. I also followed the instructions in some of the errors, but nothing worked. The code errors are a little garbled so I will do my best to format them below. I am completely new to `tensorflow` so this is completely foreign territory for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.9.0'):
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your TensorFlow installation to v1.9.* or later!')

# This is needed to display the images.
%matplotlib inline

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add the path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, ) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)

def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict

for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
```

Errors (many of them are redundant):

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     15 try:
---> 16     from . import multiarray
     17 except ImportError as exc:

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py in <module>
     11 
---> 12 from . import overrides
     13 from . import _multiarray_umath

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in <module>
      5 
----> 6 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      7     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1e9eee4e6961> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import os
      3 import six.moves.urllib as urllib
      4 import sys
      5 import tarfile

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     45 Original error was: %s
     46 """ % (sys.executable, exc)
---> 47     raise ImportError(msg)
     48 finally:
     49     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     15 try:
---> 16     from . import multiarray
     17 except ImportError as exc:

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py in <module>
     11 
---> 12 from . import overrides
     13 from . import _multiarray_umath

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in <module>
      5 
----> 6 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      7     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0f0a85121700> in <module>
      1 # This is needed to display the images.
----> 2 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2285                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2286             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2287                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2288             return result
   2289 

<c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-108> in matplotlib(self, line)

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
     97             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
     98         else:
---> 99             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
    100             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    101 

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3341         """
   3342         from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 3343         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   3344 
   3345         if gui != 'inline':

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    274     """
    275 
--> 276     import matplotlib
    277 
    278     if gui and gui != 'auto':

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    139 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    140 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 141 from . import cbook, rcsetup
    142 from matplotlib.cbook import (
    143     MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in <module>
     31 from weakref import WeakMethod
     32 
---> 33 import numpy as np
     34 
     35 import matplotlib

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     45 Original error was: %s
     46 """ % (sys.executable, exc)
---> 47     raise ImportError(msg)
     48 finally:
     49     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

The original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     15 try:
---> 16     from . import multiarray
     17 except ImportError as exc:

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py in <module>
     11 
---> 12 from . import overrides
     13 from . import _multiarray_umath

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in <module>
      5 
----> 6 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      7     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-aa270cd948af> in <module>
----> 1 from utils import label_map_util
      2 
      3 from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>
     17 import logging
     18 
---> 19 import tensorflow as tf
     20 from google.protobuf import text_format
     21 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     45 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     46 
---> 47 import numpy as np
     48 
     49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     45 Original error was: %s
     46 """ % (sys.executable, exc)
---> 47     raise ImportError(msg)
     48 finally:
     49     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using c:\users\vfx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8920c723e613> in <module>
      8 
      9 # List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
---> 10 PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NameError: name 'os' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f921d2932261> in <module>
----> 1 opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
      2 opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
      3 tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
      4 for file in tar_file.getmembers():
      5   file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)

NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d55b98fd5a78> in <module>
----> 1 detection_graph = tf.Graph()
      2 with detection_graph.as_default():
      3   od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      4   with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
      5     serialized_graph = fid.read()

NameError: name 'tf' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d9bd1cb2606d> in <module>
----> 1 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

NameError: name 'label_map_util' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-9d222f84ff65> in <module>
      4 # If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
      5 PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
----> 6 TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, ) ]
      7 
      8 # Size, in inches, of the output images.

<ipython-input-12-9d222f84ff65> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 # If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
      5 PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
----> 6 TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, ) ]
      7 
      8 # Size, in inches, of the output images.

NameError: name 'os' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b19082c2666b> in <module>
----> 1 for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      2   image = Image.open(image_path)
      3   # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      4   # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      5   image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)

NameError: name 'TEST_IMAGE_PATHS' is not defined
```

Comment: Why do people torture themselves and use Windows? ImportError says `DLL load failed`. Looks like you haven't installed Numpy properly. You might want to use a Windows tag as well for your question

Comment: @dan-klasson I reinstalled Numpy but it still isn't working

Comment: it goes on to say `Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed`. so you might want to narrow your search with installing that module for windows

Comment: @dan-klasson okay, I'll try. Thanks